# Minor alignment issue in the site's home page for the anonymous visitors

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, anonymous-visitors

When I'm visiting any Stack Exchange site with out login (as anonymous visitor), in the home page there is an alignment issue.

The grid cells are not aligned correctly in the Mozilla Firefox, Google Chrome, Microsoft Edge browsers.

> [image: Anonymous user]

When viewing from Internet Explorer 11, it is displaying correctly:

> [image: Anonymous user IE]

I'm on Windows 10 Pro, 100% zoom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A fix for this has merged in and will go live in the next build, whenever that is. Thanks for reporting!

Comment: Now it is looking good.